# Setting parse object property after save

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, cloud, pfobject

I'm trying to add a date to a PFObject after save on the cloud. The set() doesnt seem to work:

```
Parse.Cloud.afterSave("ReactMessage", function(request, status) {

    var now = new Date();
    var message = request.object;
    message.set('lastChanged',now.getTime());
    message.save();

//etc...

});
```

Or if anyone has any suggestions as to how to treat NSDate accross multiple time zones for a messaging app e.g - "X replied 20 minutes ago".
if someone sends me a message from amsterdam (im in UK) it says 'one hour ago" even though I just recieved the message

Answer (score 1):

I thinks it's better be in beforeSave request than after save.

```
Parse.Cloud.beforeSave("ReactMessage", function(request, response) {
    var now = new Date();
    var message = request.object;
    message.set('lastChanged',now.getTime());
    response.success();
});
```

That will do the trick